# npm config set: command not found error in Mac mini

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm

I have installed node Js 6.9.1 on my Mac mini (Late 2014).

All `npm` commands are working except for: `npm config set`

Due to this I'm unable to set `proxy`. Check below image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Try backspacing over `npm config set` and typing it out again – the spaces appear not to be spaces.

Comment: Thank You Ryan I again typed npm config set command for proxy and now it's working.